# Is this really not a valid xs:decimal?

Tags: xml, schema, xmllint

Here's what xmllint is telling me:

```
  '1024663.719008264462809917' is not a valid value of the atomic type 'xs:decimal'
```

Is there some default number of valid places?  There isn't supposed to be according to [this](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/xml/schema/ch16_01.htm#ch16-77036).

Update: experimenting with xmllint, 17 decimal places validates but 18 is not valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The official spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#decimal) states that

> All ·minimally conforming· processors ·must· support decimal numbers with a minimum of 18 decimal digits (i.e., with a ·totalDigits· of 18). However, ·minimally conforming· processors ·may· set an application-defined limit on the maximum number of decimal digits they are prepared to support, in which case that application-defined maximum number ·must· be clearly documented.

So while theoretically the data type allows arbitrary precision decimal numbers, a particular processor is allowed to limit the range of values it is prepared to support.

Comment: Furthermore, the spec is very vague about what a processor should do if the limit is exceeded.